merge the first line in a cell from a column , with first line in the next cell in the next column. assuming there are multiple lines in each cell
I have an excel sheet like this with cell containing multiple lines, for Ex A1 is this
data3
data6
data2
data9

And B1 is this
example2
example11
example8
example5

I want the data to be merged like this in C1
data3example
data6example11
data2example8
data9example5

Some cells have 4 lines of, some have 8 lines, etc, thus unable to change Text to column function and then concatenating, If not in Excel, would be great if could be done using python also.

Rather trivial in some versions of Excel. Which one are you using?

=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)) & TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10)))


